# Redux and Normalizr placing single entity into array

Tags: redux

I'm using Redux and Normalizr.

I have a state which looks like:

```
{
  entities: {
    users: {
      1: {...},
      2: {...}
    }
  },
  data: {
    users: [1,2]
  }
}
```

One of my API endpoints returns an object that includes a single user and some other data:

```
data = {
      user: {id: 3, ...}
      otherstuff: {...}
    }
const user = new Schema('users');

normalize(data, {user: user})
```

This returns

```
{
  entities: {
    users: {
      3: {id: 3, ...}
    }
  },
  result: {
    user: 3
  }
}
```

However my data reducer expects to merge in a users array (of ids):

```
function data(state = {}, action) {
  if (action.response && action.response.result)  {
    return deepmerge(state, action.response.result)
  }
  return state
}
```

Ideally I'd address this issue in the normalisation process rather than changing the reducer. Is there an easy way to either get normalizr to parse `{user: {id: 3}}` into `{result: {users: [3]}}`? It already changes the entities key to `users`.

If not, is there a clean and generic reducer-level solution to having this problem across a variety of entity type names?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?